# Averaging across specific trials with some overlapping labels

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that can be simplified like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101,101,101,101,101,101,
              102,102),
  `Event Full` = c('SocReframeNeg',
            'SocReframeNeg',
            'SelfReframeNeg',
            'SelfReframeNeg',
            'SocReframeNeg',
            'SocReframeNeg',
            'SocImmerseNeg',
            'SocImmerseNeg'),
  Score = c(2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8)
)
```

I want to find the average value of each trial within each subject and number each 'unique' trial. Note that there are multiple types of trial with the same label within a subject (e.g. SocReframeNeg for subject 101) and I do not want to average across all of them. I only want to average across all the rows with that label in `Event Full` until the next row becomes another value (e.g. when `Event Full` switches from SocReframeNeg to SelfReframeNeg for subject 101).

This is the desired output:

```
solution <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101, 101, 101, 102),
  Num = c(1,2,3,1),
  `Event Full` = c("SocReframeNeg", "SelfReframeNeg", 'SocReframeNeg', 'SocImmerseNeg'),
  Score = c(2.5,3.5,5.5,7.5)
)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
example |> 
  mutate(Num = consecutive_id(Event.Full), .by = Subject) |> 
  summarize(Score = mean(Score), .by = c(Subject, Event.Full, Num))
#   Subject     Event.Full Num Score
# 1     101  SocReframeNeg   1   2.5
# 2     101 SelfReframeNeg   2   3.5
# 3     101  SocReframeNeg   3   5.5
# 4     102  SocImmerseNeg   1   7.5
```